# How to configure a server for pause and resume downloads?

Tags: php, web-server, http

I am working on an iOS application, which needs basically functionality like [µTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9CTorrent). I am able to download and upload through the app using a web service (API) created in PHP.

I get to know that I should also configure my web service and server for pause and resume the downloads and uploads?

I read somewhere that, If I'll pass the `range` in `headers` of the request through my app, then if server is capable of accept the range then it'll start the download and upload from when it stopped.

I want to know how I can configure my server to accept the `ranges`? And start the upload and download from it last?

Comment: Cross posted to StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285752/pause-resume-uploading-downloading-even-if-application-terminates-is-this-pos

Comment: @Rex, Yes! I'd already posted that question on SO! Because that's for handling the stuff from iOS environment. I posted my question here for server side configurations. Let me know if you want more information.

Comment: There is no "server side" component. This would all be done in the code.

Comment: @Rex, I read somewhere that, if you'll pass `range` in a request to the server, then the server should capable to regenerate the image of that particular resource from where it stopped last. Here I am totaly unaware of those things!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720419/how-can-i-find-out-whether-a-server-supports-the-range-header

Comment: @Rex, here it is I guess! Thanks for the link, I am checking it, will get back to you soon. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all HTTP/1.1 compliant servers accept [range headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) and respond with [content-range headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16). (sysadmin part)

You don't need to change anything on webserver for ul/dl. Everything depends on how clients are downloading and uploading files. Maybe it's not the mechanism what you are looking for. (development part)

I think this is question for https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer GioMac! +1 for that. I already asked a question on SO but I think this is server related question, so I asked here:) Please let me know if you've any link for the same.

Comment: You're welcome. If you are accessing file directly - web server will do the thing. Through PHP - I don't know. My dev skills are poor.